# Bootstrap datepicker - Display in M YYYY, Send data to server in MMYYYY format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Using bootstrap datepicker to pick a date. Everything works fine as expected. But, because of server restriction we need to send data on submit like "022021" instead of "Feb 2021" now.

Not sure how to send data after formatting from original? Can help to provide any documentation or hints?

Thanks

```js
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = 'M yyyy';
$('[data-key="from_date"]').datepicker({
  format: 'M yyyy',
  viewMode: 'months', 
  minViewMode: 'months',
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  endDate: new Date()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="from_date" data-key='from_date' />

<input type="submit" class="submit-date">
```

Answer (score 0):

I test it in Fiddle.

```
Bootstrap v4.5.2
Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.9.0
```

This code should work.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date">
```

And this is the simple Javascript

```js
$('#date').datepicker({
 format: 'mmyyyy',
});
```

The result is

```
022021
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can set 2 formats 1 for display and 1 for getting data from backend.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: {
   
    toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
        return d.toISOString();
    },
    toValue: function (date, format, language) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
        return new Date(d);
    }
  },
   autoclose: true 
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. how to send data to backend "tovalue" pls?

Comment: When you will get value from jquery you will get "toValue" value in backend